# Sort the table and column by name in Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

This just bugs me everytime I want to check for a column name:

[image]

Why? `Posts` and `Users` are so important that they must appears first? `Id` is an important column, no doubt. But seriously, when we seek a column name, it is generally not for the `Id` spelling!

It takes me hours to find the right column spelling.

This would be so awesome if you made these lists alphabetically ordered!

Comment: Hours? There's like 15 tables with descriptive names, and none of the are more than ~20 columns wide.

Comment: Ok, maybe minutes... At least seconds for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

> `Posts` and `Users` are so important that they must appears first?

Well, yeah, they're pretty import tables...As far as the columns go, they're just listed in the order that they appear in the database schema.

However, I don't think that being able to sort the list alphabetically is such a terrible idea, so I've gone ahead and [submitted a commit to allow this](https://github.com/tms/StackExchange.DataExplorer/commit/d24810e8ff8b349fe74449c466c44f82cb8b06f9) with a toggle button in the header:

[image: sorting button on schema]